# Form Filling apps iOS 7+

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have an iOS app with 85% form filling screens. And data to be filled contains on an average 8-10 textfields per screen. I'm using scrollview to achieve it. I have done it but is there any proper/ideal way to make the scroll working smoothly for the textfields in potrait/landscape mode for iPhone & iPad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So they're not smooth at the moment? You might find that a table view approach would handle it better, though without seeing some more details of the app (screenshots or code) it's hard to say!